# Matrix select from database

Tags: php, sql, oracle, select, matrix

I'm trying to receive informations from a table and this information will be used divided in groups.
I would like to know if there is a way of receiving this data in some sort of a 3d matrix.
I'm doing this code in php and on oracle sql developer, but even so i can do it easily in php, i would appreciate if this information came more "organized".
Example:
Let's say that the data normally would come out like this from the database.

```
$m = array  
(
  array("field1"=>1, "field2"=>'1', "field3"=> somedata),  
  array("field1"=>1, "field2"=>'2', "field3"=> somedata), 
  array("field1"=>2, "field2"=>'3', "field3"=> somedata),  
  array("field1"=>2, "field2"=>'4', "field3"=> somedata),  
  array("field1"=>2, "field2"=>'5', "field3"=> somedata)  
);
```

I would like to it came out like this:

```
$m = array
(
  array("1" =>  $m = array  
  (
    array("field2"=>'1', "field3"=> somedata),  
    array("field2"=>'2', "field3"=> somedata)
  )),
  array("2" =>  $m = array  
  (
    array("field2"=>'3', "field3"=> somedata),  
    array("field2"=>'4', "field3"=> somedata),
    array("field2"=>'5', "field3"=> somedata)
  ))
);
```

I don't know if i've have made myself clear, but would like that i could receive this data in any kind of blocks using some column or information as parameter, any way that i could treat this information more easily on php, because i would have to do loops to split this data in sub-arrays.
Anyways, Thanks for the help and sorry for the english
P.S.: Just to clarify a little more:
Normally i would acess some data(direct from db, without any treatment) this way:

```
$ar[0]['field1'];//value 2
$ar[0]['field2'];//some value
$ar[1]['field1'];//value 2
$ar[1]['field2'];//some value
$ar[3]['field1'];//value 3
$ar[3]['field2'];//some value
```

And i want, kind of, receive this, grouped, in another "index" directly from the return from the select. And i would access it like this:

```
$ar[0]['field1'][0]; 
//would return the same as this($ar[0]) from the example above
$ar[0]['field1'][1]; 
//would return the same as this($ar[2]) from the example above
$ar[1]['field1'][0]; 
//would return the same as this($ar[3]) from the example above
```

Comment: Data comes back as rows and columns.  What you do with it after that is up to you.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is that I want to receive it back from the select as an 3d matrix. Change after receive is indeed easy and up to me, my question is if i can make the return from select to be someway close to the example i've written

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can use ROLLUP and CUBE which provides subtotals.
You can then sort and process the details in order.
Regards,
Jose